# Why php array inital assign syntax, is different from later assign?

Tags: php

Example:

```
$fruits = ['first' => 'apple'];

$fruits = [];
$fruits['first'] = 'apple';
```

Why is not allowed initialize like this?

```
$fruits = ['first' = 'apple'];
```

Is there historical, or logical reasons for this?

Comment: It makes no sense. `=` is a variable assignment operator. `'first'` is not a variable. By the way, you don't have to use `$fruits = ['first' => 'apple'];` for the initial one. You can use `$fruits['first'] = 'apple';` in its place and it wouldn't be any different.

Answer (score 0):

Because a key is not equal (=) to a value, it refers to it (=>).